# How to change the default favicon for media URLs in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I wants to show an image from media folder to frontend by accessing the link like

http://{siteurl}/media/image.jpg

here my problem is on the top of browser the tab it shows default magento favicon instead of my faviocon.

how can I show my faviocon in media URLs instead of the default faviocn.

any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can change favicon icon from

`System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Favicon Icon`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer with the screen shot attached
but I have already followed these steps and on the other front end pages it is already displaying my favicon but when I am trying to access the media URL at that tim it shows default faviocon instead of mine.